# Use Windows password in WinSCP script

Tags: authentication, sftp, windows-authentication, winscp

Is it possible to automatically use Windows password in WinSCP script? Instead of typing it in script file.

script.txt file consists:

```
open MyUserName:MyPassword@MySFTPserver.net
option transfer binary
get TestFile.txt c:\
close
```

winscp.bat that triggers the script contains

```
winscp.exe /console /script=script.txt
```

Comment: Is your SFTP server in the same domain as your local machine? Or are the passwords just coincidentally the same?

Comment: Yes SFTP server user password replicates with domain password. So the password to SFTP server and local machine are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinSCP (nor any other application) cannot retrieve your password from Windows. It's not possible in general, it would be a security threat.

Anyway, WinSCP supports Kerberos/GSSAPI/SSPI authentication that allows you to reuse your domain authentication for connection to an SSH/SFTP server. So you may be able to use that, if your SSH/SFTP server supports that.

```
open sftp://MyUserName@MySFTPserver.net /rawsettings AuthGSSAPI=1
```

---

References:

- [WinSCP Authentication options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication)
- [Raw Site Settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings)